# Dynamic Index Creation - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, scheduled-tasks

Ok, so I work for a company who sells a web product which has a MS SQL Server back end (can be any version, we've just changed our requirements to 2008+ now that 05 is out of extended support). All databases are owned by the company who purchases the product but we have VPN access and have a tech support department to deal with any issues. One part of my role is to act as 3rd line support for SQL issues.

When performance is a concern one of the usual checks is unused/missing indexes. We've got the usual standard indexes but depending on which modules or how a company utilises the system then it will require different indexes (there's an accounting module and a document management module amongst others). With hundreds of customers it's not possible to remote onto each on a regular basis in order to carry out optimisation work. I'm wondering if anybody else in my position has considered a scheduled task that may be able to drop and create indexes when needed?

I've got concerns (obviously), any changes that this procedure makes would also be stored in a table with full details of the change and a time stamp. I'd need this to be bullet proof, can't be sending something out into the wild if it may cause issues. I'm thinking an overnight or (probably) weekly task.

Dropping Indexes:

- Would require the server to be up for a minimum amount of time to ensure all relevant server statistics are up to date (say 2 weeks or 1 month).
- Only drop unused indexes for tables that are being actively used (indexes on unused parts of the system aren't a concern).
- Log it.
- This won't highlight duplicate indexes (that will have to be manual), just the quick wins (unused indexes with writes).

Creating Indexes

- Only look for indexes with a value above a certain threshold.
- Would have to check whether any similar indexes could be modified to cover the requirement. This could be on a ranking (check all indexed fields are the same and then score the included fields to see if additional would be needed).
- Limit to a maximum number of indexes to be created (say 5 per week) to ensure it doesn't get carried away and create a bunch at once). This should help only focus on the most important indexes.
- Log it.

This would need to be dynamic as we've got customers on different versions of the system with different usage patterns.

Just to clarify: I'm not expecting anybody to code for this, it's more a question relating to the feasibility and concerns for a task like this.

**Edit:** I've put a bounty on this to gather some further opinions and to get feedback from anybody who may have tried this before. I'll award it to the answer with the most upvotes by the time the bounty duration ends.

Comment: Why would you go from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008, rather than 2014 or 2016?

Comment: It's a minimum requirement. Ultimately it's a customer's decision which version they're on. If it were a customer on 2005 then we require them to upgrade, they can pick the version (it's their server). If the customer was on 2008 then we wouldn't require them to upgrade.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've never worked in a  corporate environment where an infrastructure upgrade is realised simply to accommodate a single piece of software.  A minimum requirement of 2008 gives a much larger potential client base...

Comment: I could see dropping unused indexes but creating indexes dynamically seems like a bad idea. You should use the missing indexes as suggestions and evaluate if they are actually a good idea. You have to look at the bigger picture. I've had many times where an index was suggested but instead I could add another column to an existing index and save some space but increase performance. Just saying, I'd be extra careful.

Comment: Sure, it's definitely a concern with creating new indexes. That's why I'd want it to consider things like similar indexes (e.g. come up with a system that determines how similar the options are). It would also require a threshold (say, do the 5 most important indexes per week this would stop it going out of control). At the moment I am the bottleneck for this within the business, trying to take that out of the equation. The other option is to train the developers/support on this but it would have to be trusted users due to how complex it can be.

Comment: Maybe there is a midway approach where you could add more standard indexes based on modules used?

Comment: Possibly, but it would mean gathering data on a wide range of customers. The issue is that customers may not even use the same module in the same way, it's a pretty versatile piece of software. Also, number of users will have an effect, we have ranges from dozens up to hundreds which obviously has an effect on index requirements too.

Comment: One concern would be running the system out of disk space by adding new indexes.  Since it needs to be bulletproof, you would want to calculate about how much disk space a new index would take before creating it, and check to see if there is adequate free disk space.  Honestly, I would just have it email the suggested indexes and create a support ticket, then a human can quickly review the suggestions and take just a few minutes to run the script to create the indexes.  That would be much safer, require minimal support time, and have the intended result (stay ahead of performance issues).

Comment: Some relevant links here http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44002/3690

Comment: In short: it is a difficult problem (in the NP-hard sense). By deleting an index you risk that it would take days instead of minutes to generate a "very important report" at the end of the financial year and the rest of the system would be barely usable during this time. If you create too many indexes, optimiser would start failing to choose the best execution plan. There will be simply too many possible variants for optimiser to analyse. Link to dba.se by @MartinSmith is great.

Comment: Maybe you like to have a look here: https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/ This site has a bunch of optimizing stuff for MS-SQL-Servers the linked SP gives you advice what to do.

Comment: Yeah, I actively use the Brent Ozar scripts including sp_BlitzIndex when jumping on a site but it only makes suggestions, it doesn't make any changes by itself. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: what about not going so far as to drop and create indexes automatically, but something that monitors performance or points you to customers who need to have some special index attention.  You would still handle the index changes, but you would know which customers to look at first.  If that works well, then you can proceed with trying to automate the index manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't recommend what you're contemplating, but you might be able to simplify your life by gathering the inputs to your contemplated program and making them available to clients and the support team.

If the problem were as simple as you suppose, surely the server itself or the tuning advisor would have solved it by now.  You're making at least one unwarranted assumption,

> require the server to be up for a minimum amount of time to ensure all relevant server statistics are up to date.

Table statistics are only as good as the last time the were updated after a significant change.  Uptime won't guarantee anything about *truncate table* or a bulk insert.

> This won't highlight duplicate indexes

But that's something you *can* do in a single query using the system tables.  (It would be disappointing if the tuning gadget didn't help with those.)   You could similarly look for overlapping indexes, such as for columns {a,b} and {a}; the second won't be useful unless {b} is selective *and* there are queries that don't mention {b}.

To look for new indexes, I would be tempted to try to instrument query use frequency and automate the analysis of query plan output.  If you can identify frequently used, long-running queries and map their physical operations (table scan, hash join, etc.) onto the tables and existing indexes, you would have good *input* for adding and removing indexes.  But you have to allow for the infrequently run quarterly report that, without its otherwise unused index, would take days to complete.

I must tell you that when I did that kind of analysis once some years ago, I was disappointed to learn that most problem children were awful queries, usually prompted by awful table design.  No index will help the SQL mule.  Hopefully that will not be your experience.

An aspect you didn't touch on that might be just as important is machine capacity.  You might look into gathering, say, hourly snapshots of SQL Server stats, like disk queue depth and paging.  Hardly a server exists that can't be improved with more RAM, and sometimes that's really the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

SQL perf tuning advisor worth a check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186232.aspx

another way could be to get performance data, start here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17780/Monitoring-table-level-activity-in-a-SQL-Server-database-by-using-T-SQL.html and generate indexes based on the performance table data

check this too : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817826.aspx